# Animate one - Stop another | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know what am I doing wrong but nothing is correct.
Basically it works just fine but if I hover over another list item it starts animation and previous one remain.

Here's JS part...

```
$('nav#topMenu li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if(e.type === 'mouseenter') {
        $(this).append('<span class="active"></span>');
        $('span.active').stop().slideDown('200');
    } else {
        $('span.active').stop().slideUp('200', function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

Here's JS fiddle:
[JS Fiddle redirect](http://jsfiddle.net/HL7Aj/)

Sorry for that ugly hover background color...
I have no ideas although what I am doing wrong... Appears to be everything wrong!
Any solution is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Appears that I am also appending that span on every single hover, even if it's already appended to the list item. Oh my ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because both spans still have the class `active`.  The `mouseleave` occurs first, but `mouseenter` triggers `.stop().slideDown()` on *both* spans.

There are several possible solutions, but I think one is to just use `.removeClass('active')` on the span (possibly adding another class with the same styles).  This will cause it to slide all the way up while the true active span slides down:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/HL7Aj/1/

Comment: Quite cool... However in my edit I've mentioned that it keeps appending on hovering of active item...
I think the best solution would be to think of better way to add the active item styling...

However +1 for this , at least it works.

Comment: @user1658136 Don't use `.active` for the styling class.  Just use a separate class purely for the styling and `.active` only to check that it's active.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the animation is completed with `.is(":animated")`. Since `$('span.active')` selects all the elements with the `active` class, you effectively stop the animation on all of them as you move your cursor across elements. You should apply further animation on those elements on the condition that they are not carrying out any existing animations.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5ggGL/).

```
$(function () {
    $('nav#topMenu li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        if(e.type === 'mouseenter') {
            $(this).append('<span class="active"></span>');
            $('span.active').each(function() {
                if (!$(this).is(":animated")) {
                    $(this).stop().slideDown('200');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('span.active').stop().slideUp('200', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that replacing

> $('span.active').stop()

with

> $(this).find('span.active').stop()

may help you.